# Frames streaming via socket

Tags: java, android, networking, bigdata

I am making an android app where i should send camera frames via udp/tcp socket
I get each frame as a byte[] array in a FrameCallback 
Then i used the socket to send each time MAX_BUFFER_SIZE bytes from the array
as fragments.
But it's not Effcient enough since the array size sent is about 10M, and there will be alot of buffering when the stream will be desplayed.
I can't compress the array too since it's an OMEGA(n) operation, SO
First of all , what protocol is better for this problem? UDP, TCP ?
And in general , how can i send that huge array over socket in a video streaming efficiency level ?

Comment: 'Frames', 'streaming', and 'UDP' are already mutually contradictory in several axes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it by using the UDP Protocol
And used Allocation class to compress the data array, it did the work!